# Initialize member of the struct

Tags: c, struct

In C, I'm trying to initialise a structure's member but I'm unable to do it. Here is my code construct:

```
struct values{
  int a;
  int b;
  int b;
  int d;
 };
struct values value[65535];
```

I want to initialise b member of the structure to -1 for all the values in the struct object array. I'm unable to figure out good way to do this.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  GCC has an non-standard extension that makes it easy; Clang probably supports it too for GCC compatibility.  Otherwise, there isn't an easy way to do it.

Comment: Loop over them and set it?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
for (i = 0; i < 65535; i++)
    value[i].b = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct values{
  int a;
  int b=-1;
  int c;
  int d;
 };
struct values value[65535];
int main(){
    printf("%d",value[2].b);
    return 0;
}
```

Tell me if this helps.

Comment: Which language is this code for?  Or, if you think it is C, which compiler?

Comment: Question is asked in c

Comment: Yes, but the code you show is not valid C — that's why I asked which language or which compiler.

Comment: compiler TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit

Comment: I don't know the significance of the `TDM` prefix, but standard GCC 6.2.0 (and 4.9.1) rejects it: `error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token` and identifies `int b=-1;` as the code that causes the error.  That's compiling with no options specified to make it compile more stringently.